# DBMS_SQL.LAST_ERROR_POSITION: error position for PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

What is the equivalent for [`DBMS_SQL.LAST_ERROR_POSITION`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-7C0A6BED-4368-433B-845F-8D9710742838) in PostgreSQL to get the offset of an error?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify in what programming language you want to access this information, and not all APIs give you access to the location of the error, but it is sent with the PostgreSQL error message.

See [the documentation for the C API](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQRESULTERRORFIELD):

> `PQresultErrorField`
>
> Returns an individual field of an error report.
>
> ```
> char *PQresultErrorField(const PGresult *res, int fieldcode);
> ```
>
> `fieldcode` is an error field identifier; see the symbols listed below. `NULL` is returned if the `PGresult` is not an error or warning result, or does not include the specified field. Field values will normally not include a trailing newline. The caller should not free the result directly. It will be freed when the associated `PGresult` handle is passed to `PQclear`.
>
> The following field codes are available:
>
> [...]
>
> `PG_DIAG_STATEMENT_POSITION`
>
> A string containing a decimal integer indicating an error cursor position as an index into the original statement string. The first character has index 1, and positions are measured in characters not bytes.
>
> `PG_DIAG_INTERNAL_POSITION`
>
> This is defined the same as the `PG_DIAG_STATEMENT_POSITION` field, but it is used when the cursor position refers to an internally generated command rather than the one submitted by the client. The `PG_DIAG_INTERNAL_QUERY` field will always appear when this field appears.

Comment: I want to identify the error position in a query which is being executed inside a postgresql function(PLPGSQL)

Comment: That's not available (yet) in PL/pgSQL. If you are so inclined, it would not be too hard to add that functionality, and you won't meet much resistance.